# XML serialization national chars error

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-serialization

EDIT:

Doing too much.... this works for me with national chars

```
                var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ToDoItem));
                var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                xs.Serialize(stringWriter, item);
                var test = XDocument.Parse(stringWriter.ToString());
```

...where The item is the object containing strings with national chars

/EDIT

I did a project with serialization of some objects.

I copied some code from examples on this site and everything worked great, till I changed framework ASP.NET from 3.5 til 4.0... (and changed ISS7 .net setting from v2.0 to v4.0)

I am 99% sure this is the cause of the following error:

Before this change something like this:

```
                var test = XDocument.Parse(SerializeObject("æøåAØÅ", typeof(string)));
                test.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("test.xml"));
```

Would save the xml with the exact chars used.

Now it saves this:
 ���A��

I would like: Information on settings I might have to make in IIS7

OR

A comment on how to change the serializing methods to handle the national chars better.

This is the serialization code used.

```
  private static String UTF8ByteArrayToString(Byte[] characters)
    {
        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

        String constructedString = encoding.GetString(characters);

        return (constructedString);
    }



    public static String SerializeObject(Object pObject, Type type)
    {
        try
        {
            String XmlizedString = null;
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(type);
            var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.ASCII);


            xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, pObject);
            memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
            XmlizedString = UTF8ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            return XmlizedString.Trim();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save a text as using ASCII and then decode it using UTF-8 and expect that it will work? It won't. This code could never work properly, regardless of any updates or settings.

There is no need to write the XML to a `MemoryStream` and then decode that. Just use [`StringWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx):

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(type);
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
xs.Serialize(stringWriter, pObject);
return stringWriter.ToString();
```

Comment: Well -  my bad. The result was kept in memory and never saved to file, so that was not the issue. However - I found out that I WAS doing too much, and your example enabled me to cut that away. The serialized objects were of course more complex than the string example, but not to any problem

Comment: It doesn't matter that the result was never saved to a file. When converting string to `byte[]`, which you (indirectly) did, the encoding is used.